# Using the Open XML SDK to manipulate Wrod how do I move the cursor to a particular paragraph

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Please help me, when using the Open XML SDK to generate a Word document through the Word template in the.net core platform, how do I move the cursor to a specific paragraph?

> 中文：在.net core 平台下使用Open XML SDK 通过Word模板生成Word文档时，如何将光标移动到特定的段落？

Comment: There is no concept of a cursor in the Open XML SDK - if you want to manipulate a specific paragraph, you need to obtain a reference to the corresponding `Paragraph` object in the document.

Answer (score 0):

@Bradley Smith comment is right.
We use [Open XML SDK 2.5 productivity tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)
from Microsoft, there you could write 
a docx with the layout you want to achieve and reflect it into C# code.
I think its good for getting started with OpenXml.

Comment: I need to generate a word document through a template, and the tables involved are dynamically generated. You need to populate the content by wrapping lines and moving the cursor

Comment: Did you find a solution?